# Setting div background image url with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
var _options = {
        button_delete_src: '/Content/images/delete_button.png'
    };

var _css = {
        button_delete: {
            'background': 'url(\'' + _options.button_delete_src + '\') no-repeat;'
        }
    };

$('<div></div>').css(_css.button_delete).appendTo(container);
```

Created div does not have background css set in rendered html. Can you help me?

EDIT: working in IE, but not in Chrome

Comment: make sure your relative path is correct too

Comment: relative path is correct

Comment: @techie_28 I have not tried that, it's wrong I think

Comment: oh yes it should be $('#divId').css({'background' : 'url(\'' + _options.button_delete_src + '\') no-repeat;' })

Comment: Have you have a URL where we can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working:

```
$(function(){
var _options = {
    button_delete_src: 'http://bigcrow.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/my-tattoo.jpg'
};

var _css = {
    button_delete: {
        'width': '1000px',
        'height':'1000px',
        'background': 'url(' + _options.button_delete_src + ') no-repeat'
    }
};

$('<div></div>').css(_css.button_delete).appendTo('#container');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work based on your code:

```
$('<div></div>').css('background',_css.button_delete.background).appendTo(container);
```

But i think you want something like this:

```
var $div =  $('<div></div>');    
for(var key in _css.button_delete)
    $div.css(key,_css.button_delete[key]);

$div.appendTo(container);
```